# Using expression(paste( to insert math notation into a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I wish to substitute the following (yes, I've written it here in TeX format, just to be clear)
`$P_{M1}(\tilde{z}>z) - P_{M0}(\tilde{z}>z)$`
for the green line's legend entry (cptsdtbehavioralm), and
`$P_{M2}(\tilde{z}>z) - P_{M0}(\tilde{z}>z)$`
for the blue line's legend entry (fullbehavioralmodel).

Here is the code with which I generated the plot (I am omitting the 10,000-observation dataset and the transforms to generate the functions Fm0, Fm1 and Fm2):

```
bmp("bias_plot_v4.bmp", width=540, pointsize=10)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,80)),aes(x) ) +
   stat_function(fun=function(x)((1-Fm1(x)) - (1- Fm0(x))), geom="line", 
aes(colour="cptsdtbehavioralm"), n=1000) +
   stat_function(fun=function(x)((1-Fm2(x)) - (1- Fm0(x))), geom="line", 
aes(colour="fullbehavioralmodel"), n=1000) +
 theme_bw() +
   ylab("Probability") +
 xlab(expression(paste("Security breaches per 3-week spear-phishing campaign ", 
italic( (z) )))) +  
 theme(aspect.ratio=.618) + 
   theme(legend.position=c(0.845,0.8)) +
   theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("cptsdtbehavioralm"="green2", 
"fullbehavioralmodel" = "blue"), name="Bias")
dev.off()
```

Whenever I try to replace the "cptsdtbehavioralm" and "fullbehavioralmodel" with a math expression -- e.g. to keep it simple, `expression(P[{M1}])` -- I get the following type of errors:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"       theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c(expression(P[{M1}]))="
```

I'm at my wit's end -- any insight or suggestions would be very, very welcome.

Comment: This example is highly **un**reproducible. Create a small example, and the code that will return the error. At the moment it appears you have mistyped your equation, (closing a parenthesis prematurely), but that is purely guesswork....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to use `values` and `labels` to get what I think you want.

Note that `values` map the values in the data to the colours you wish to use, while `labels` are the labels you want displayed (so this is where you would put the expression).

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x= c(0,5)),aes(x=x)) +
    stat_function(fun=dnorm,aes(colour = 'red')) + 
    stat_function(fun = dexp, aes(colour = 'blue')) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = c('red' = 'red','blue' = 'blue'),name = '', 
          labels = expression(P[M1](tilde(z)>0),P[M0](tilde(z)>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you *very* much mnel -- you did see through my less-than-fully-transparent question. I had cobbled the code together from numerous other examples and posts here and elsewhere. Thanks to you, my code now not only works, but it is cleaner and clearer! I'd vote you up, but my experience is too low at the moment (this was my first post).