# Annotate with greater than or equal to in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I want to annotate a ggplot with the phrase "Large fish ≥ 45cm" but can't seem to achieve it.
I tried the following example but it produces an "=". Also adding "45" throws up an error.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp))+
geom_point()+
annotate("text",25,400, label=("Fish*~symbol('\u2265')*~cm"), parse=TRUE, hjust=0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp))+
    geom_point()+
    annotate("text",25,400, label=("'Large fish' >= 45 ~ 'cm'"), parse=TRUE, hjust=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution is based on the `latex2exp` package (an R package that parses and converts LaTeX math formulas to R’s `plotmath` expressions):

```
library(latex2exp)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp))+
 geom_point()+
 annotate("text",25,400,
          label=TeX("Fish $\\geq$ 45 cm", output="character"),
          hjust=0, parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: ggplot returns exactly $\geq$ and in the pdf from Latex it's also $\geq$. How to make it to display ≥?

Comment: I specifically want to write "≥" symbol in a label of the legend.

Comment: @Laura You can use the solution proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507742/using-expressionpaste-to-insert-math-notation-into-a-legend