# Annotate ggplot with multiline text and parse characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently annotating my ggplot2 with the following text:

```
 annotate("text",x= 40, y=40, label = "18 (23.1%) >= 10%\n 33 (42.3%)
 <10% and >= 3%\n 27 (34.6%) < 3%", size = 4, parse = TRUE)
```

and I would like to convert the greater than or equal to text into the symbol, however I am receiving the following error:

```
 Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : <text>:2:26: unexpected
 input 1: 18 (23.1%) >= 10% 2:  33 (42.3%) <10% and >= 3%
```

Could you please help me modify my annotation so that it is accurately parsable?
Thank you very much.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Why do you need to parse this? You don't appear to be using any plotmath in there.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587386/annotate-with-greater-than-or-equal-to-in-ggplot